# How to stop htmlpy ui blocking

Tags: python, youtube, backend

I was working on a small downloader for `Youtube` videos using `trollius` (for async), htmlpy and pafy (and youtube-dl). Now i have a problem where once i click the download button, the UI freezes up while the `backend` is downloading the video.

I have tried to make the `downloader` class its own thread and run that alongside the `UI` but that doesn't seem to work. I also tried to uses `coroutine` to have the video download asynchronously while the `UI` continues. Neither seemed to work.

Here is some code

```
class Downloader(htmlPy.Object,threading.Thread):
dd = os.path.join(os.getenv('USERPROFILE'), 'Downloads')  # dd = download director
dd = dd + "/vindownload/"

def __init__(self, app):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    super(Downloader, self).__init__()
    # Initialize the class here, if required.
    self.app = app
    return

@htmlPy.Slot(str)
def download_single(self, json_data):
    form_data = json.loads(json_data)
    print json_data
    url = form_data["name"]
    dt = form_data["dt"]  # Download type is audio or video
    if url.__contains__("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="):
        if dt == 'audio':
            print "hello1"
            loop = trollius.get_event_loop()
            loop.run_until_complete(self._downloadVid(url, vid=False))
            loop.stop()
        else:
            print "hello1"
            loop = trollius.get_event_loop()
            loop.run_until_complete(self._downloadVid(url, vid=True))
            loop.stop()
        self.app.evaluate_javascript("document.getElementById('form').reset()")
    else:
        print "Incorrect url"
    print form_data

 @trollius.coroutine
def _downloadVid(self, url, vid=False, order_reverse=False, vinName=None):
    print "hello123"
    video = pafy.new(url)
    print video
    name = u''.join(video.title).encode('utf8')
    name = re.sub("[<>:\"/\\|?*]", "", name)
    if not vid:
        file = video.getbestaudio()
    else:
        file = video.getbest()
    if (order_reverse):
        file.download(self.dd + vinName + name + ".mp4", quiet=False,callback=self.mycb)
    else:
        file.download(self.dd + name + ".mp4", quiet=False,callback=self.mycb)

def mycb(self,total, recvd, ratio, rate, eta):
    print(recvd, ratio, eta)
```

and my initialize.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname("initilize.py"))

app = htmlPy.AppGUI(title=u"Vin download", width=700, height=400, resizable=False)

app.static_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
app.template_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates/")

app.web_app.setMaximumWidth(830)
app.web_app.setMaximumHeight(600)

download  = Downloader(app)
download.start()

# Register back-end functionalities
app.bind(download)
app.template = ("./index.html", {"template_variable_name": "value"})

# Instructions for running application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # The driver file will have to be imported everywhere in back-end.
    # So, always keep app.start() in if __name__ == "__main__" conditional
    app.start()
```

Now my question is. Is there a way where i can free up my `UI` while downloading so it doesn't look like the application crashed.

I am using: Python 2.7, Trollius, Pafy, Youtube-dl, HTMLPY.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i found the answer to my question, here is what i did. i changed my download_single method to the following:

```
@htmlPy.Slot(str)
def download_single(self, json_data):
    form_data = json.loads(json_data)
    print json_data
    url = form_data["name"]
    dt = form_data["dt"]  # Download type is audio or video
    videoDown = videoDownload(url, dt, self.app, self.dd)
    videoDown.start()
    print form_data
```

And the code i had in it earlier is now transferred to a new class called videoDownload taking all those attributes stated above.

videoDownload.py

```
class videoDownload(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, url, dt, app, dd):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.url = url
    self.dt = dt
    self.app = app
    self.dd = dd

def run(self):
    threads.append(self)
    if self.url.__contains__("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="):
        if self.dt == 'audio':
            print "hello1"
            self._downloadVid(self.url, vid=False)
        else:
            print "hello1"
            self._downloadVid(self.url, vid=True)
    else:
        print "Incorrect url"

def _downloadVid(self, url, vid=False, order_reverse=False, vinName=None):
    print "hello123"
    video = pafy.new(url)
    print video
    name = u''.join(video.title).encode('utf8')
    name = re.sub("[<>:\"/\\|?*]", "", name)
    if not vid:
        file = video.getbestaudio()
    else:
        file = video.getbest()
    if (order_reverse):
        file.download(self.dd + vinName + name + ".mp4", quiet=False, callback=self.mycb)
    else:
        file.download(self.dd + name + ".mp4", quiet=False, callback=self.mycb)
    threads.remove(self)

def mycb(self, total, recvd, ratio, rate, eta):
    pass
```

This solved the issues i had with ui being blocked. The thread will end itself once leaving the run method and it will be removed from a threads array that is defined above the class.

Have a great day all

~Ellisan